# Watermarks without using background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to convert an html code to pdf using [selectpdf web api](https://selectpdf.com/) which contains watermark image as background image. But the issues is it's not printing background images in pdf.

Is there any other way I can add watermark effect without using background-image. Please note, water mark needs to be repeated x & y to fill the page. Watermark is just an text turned 30dg. would prefere html/css first worst case can try javascript.

Thanks

Comment: unfortunately javascript doesn't seem to be supported as well. their website says its supported (don't have any way to contact them!!!)

Comment: talking bout library I am using "selectpdf" : https://selectpdf.com/

Comment: can you please share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.watermark {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
  .watermark.wm1 {
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
  }
  .watermark.wm2 {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  }
  .watermark.wm3 {
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
  }
  .watermark.wm4 {
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
  }
  .watermark.wm5 {
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/25/16/54/african-lion-2888519_1280.jpg" />
  
  <div class="watermark wm1">WATERMARK!</div>
  <div class="watermark wm2">WATERMARK!</div>
  <div class="watermark wm3">WATERMARK!</div>
  <div class="watermark wm4">WATERMARK!</div>
  <div class="watermark wm5">WATERMARK!</div>
</div>
```

If that doesn't cut it for you, you can always use a js lib that merges watermarks with images to make them more secure. A great library is [watermark.js](https://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/)

Comment: this won't fill the page as you only got 5 elements. I am not using it for image, it text based invoice/table

Comment: @Bhavesh the concept is the same - you can add any type of content in place of `<img />`, and make as many watermarks as you need

Comment: that's the trick here - size is dynamic (unknown at design time) - dirty way would be to just add 10000s of these elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.watermark{
font-size:75px;
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top:0px;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 color:#ccc;
 top:50%;
 transform-origin:bottom bottom;
 z-index:-999;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Watermark</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class='watermark'>WATERMARK</span>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check This..! May this Help you

```css
.watermark{
font-size:75px;
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top:0px;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 color:#ccc;
 top:50%;
 transform-origin:bottom bottom;
 z-index: 1000;
    color: #ccc4c4c7;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
img {
height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Watermark</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class='watermark'>WATERMARK</span>
<img src="https://images3.alphacoders.com/853/thumb-1920-85305.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```